# Android kits not found after Android setup in Qt Creator 12.0.1

Tags: android, qt, mobile, installation, qt-creator

I have setup **Qt Creator Version 12.0.1** and I have tried installing two Qt versions **Qt 6.6.1** and **Qt 5.15.2**. For both versions, I am not able to see the kits even though Android is completely set up. Even Android Emulators and everything seem to be working fine.

[image: Android setup Completed]

[image: Android Kits not found]

[image: Qt Version showing some error]

Here it shows that there is some error:

```
Failed to detect the ABIs used by the Qt version. Check the settings in Devices > Android for errors.
```

But complete android setup is done and running:
[image: Android Device Added]

I have tried installing multiple times and also different version of Java but with the latest `sdkmanager` Java-17 is only supported.

I have tried installing the software multiple times and installing OpenJDK multiple times but still no solution. I am hoping if everything works fine then I am able to get Automatic Kits and compile the software

Comment: I think kits are manually added by the user. I did mine like that. You only need to change the "Device" option to Android.

Comment: @KeyikedalubeNdang I tried that as well but still it is not able to compile, as first these errors needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the 'cache' folder in AppData-> Local -> QtProject -> Qt Creator.
Restart the Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Android Qt Kit won't be automatically detected and shown in the "Kits" selector if the matching Android NDK is not installed.

For example Qt 6.3.2 requires NDK 22.1.7171670

This is documented here https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-getting-started.html for Qt 6.6:

> The required version of the Android NDK for 6.6 is 25.1.8937393